# When does Mocking Demise trigger?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

When using Mirror Image with the Mocking Demise rune, the images deal damage and have a chance to stun in an area when they die.

My question is, what exactly triggers this? Does this occur no matter how the Mirror Image dies? Does it trigger when the image dies because time on the spell is up? When it's destroyed by damage (this one seems the most obvious.)? What about when it's forced to die because you've re-cast Mirror Image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocking demise only triggers when your mirror images are killed (i.e. their health is reduced to 0) before their timer runs out.  There is no other condition where they explode.

Comment: That makes it rather worthless, unfortunately :(

Comment: @StrixVaria yea it is :/  I found a legendary hat that made my MIs resppawn when they die, but the problem is they rarely die before the timer runs out.  MI's duration is just way too short.